# Statistics of DFT of a random vector

Tags: probability

Say, I have a vector of IID random variables: **X**=$[x_1 x_2 ..x_N]$.
Now, I compute the N point DFT of this random vector. Will the resultant vector be iid in general?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  If the $X_i$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$ Gaussians, yes.

Edited after justly chiding comment: In general, linear functions of independent random variables are not independent: if you think about joint density functions, for (say) $X$ and $Y$ to be independent and $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ to also be independent leads to functional equations of the form $f(u)g(v)=r(u+v)s(u-v)$, which typically  only have solutions of very special form.  In your case, the DFT is an *orthogonal* linear transformation.  The peculiar form of the normal density function makes the joint distribution of  iid mean 0 Gaussians rotationally symmetric.